# How to deal with Icon@2x.png in svn?

Tags: iphone, svn

I want to check in my icons and other PNGs. Of course, I'm following the iPhone image naming convention, so I have Icon.png, and Icon@2x.png, Default.png and Default@2x.png.

One problem: svn thinks I'm trying to add something with a pinned version.

```
hacksaw > svn add Default@2x.png
svn: warning: 'Default' not found

hacksaw > ls -l Default@2x.png
-rw-r--r--@ 1 hacksaw  hacksaw  11139 Mar  1 14:44 Default@2x.png
```

Is there an alternate syntax for the 2x file? Or is there an escape that svn uses that I can't seem to find in the red-bean book?

I've thought about switching to git, but I'd really like to put it off until I finish this submission.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[How to Add Those @2x iOS4 Resources to SVN](http://developers.enormego.com/view/add_2x_ios4_resources_svn)

```
$ svn add Default@2x.png@
A (bin) Default@2x.png
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to append '@' to any filename that already contains '@', e.g. `svn add "Default@2x.png@"`.

If you want to add lots of files containing '@', and you're using bash or similiar, the following snippet is very handy:

```
for i in '*@*'; do svn add "$i@"; done
```

Comment: NOTE: I've just edited my snippet, I'd omitted a '@' character.

Answer (score 1):

If you place all resource file of default@2x.png in a folder like Resource-ipad then add this folder on svn add path. you not need to append @ at the end of the .png

Answer (score 0):

Using svn with Xcode will also solve it.

Comment: In Xcode 3, I found a number of problems. The main one is that I develop on two different machines: a laptop for most things, as I get more done if I work away from home, but a desktop for graphics work, it has Illustrator installed. And compiles quickly, etc, etc. This two machine thing causes a problem because of how Xcode deals with the xcodeproj file, which is a bundle. The files inside are checked in, but change from machine to machine, causing conflicts. If I stick in the shell for svn stuff, it's easier.